# How to confirm that isc-dhcp service works in Ubuntu server 16.04?

Tags: dhcp, vmware-player

I have problem with restart ISC-DHCP service when I type command: `**sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart**`, it show nothing.[I have no idea what is going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLOKH.pn)

I use VIM as editor to my configuration:

```
 sudo vim /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

Below here configuration files that i edited:

```
#Global Directives
authoritatives;
ddns-updates off;
ddns-update-style none;
allow unknown-clients;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
log-facility local7;

#DHCP scope
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0{
  pool{
    range 192.168.1.110 192.168.1.220;
    option subnet-netmask 255.255.255.0;
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
   }
}
```

I edited interfaces information in:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
```

Here is what I set:

```
INTERFACES = "ens38"
```

Interface "ens38" which custom Virtual network adapter in VMware.
Reason I used custom is that I do not want to cause DHCP conflict in the real network:

In case, I may made mistake through:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

Here is my configuration:

```
 #Interfaces for dhcp service
 auto ens38;
 iface ens38 inet static
 address 192.168.1.0
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.1.0
 broadcast 192.168.1.255
 gateway 192.168.1.1
 dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
 dns-search google.com
```

Comment: Did you create that particular service file? If so, which tutorial did you follow? Can you post the contents of that service file. Don't forget to start your comments with @Raphael when replying to my comments, otherwise I might miss them.

Comment: @Raphael I refer the configuration from tutorial : [link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YZDtfLzjS4

Comment: @Raphael anyway I really thanks for your awareness. I have posted the configuration relating to isc-dhcp-server service.

Comment: @derHugo I tried several time. The VM I used as clients is linux mint. It did not get IP according my DHCP pool. I remember when I tried `/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart` it showed `failed to bring up ens38`.

Answer (score 1):

check your config file

```
#Global Directives
authoritatives;
```

That should say:

```
#Global Directives
authoritative;
```

Remove the "s" at the end.

Comment: Please use code block formatting for the config file content. Just edit your answer, mark the lines from the config file and press the '{}' button on the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Right after your command do

```
sudo service isc-dhcp-server status
```

Alternatively you can still use the old

```
sudo /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart
```

.. this one is more verbose during restarting and shows errors immediately.

Anyway to confirm if the service works... connect another PC to your network and see if it can get an IP via DHCP ;)